# Is there a way to make a factory without defining a base class in c++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-method

I work with Qt and one thing that is bothering me is the fact that I have to use QObject to use qRegisterMetaType.
I tried to implement the factory method by my own with success but I still need to use an abstract class.

Is it possible to do the same thing without defining a base class (in this case object)?

Working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>

class object
{
    public:

    virtual ~object(){}

    virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};

class SomeObject : public object
{
    public:

    SomeObject(){}
    virtual ~SomeObject(){}

    virtual std::string to_string()
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeObject";
    } 
};

class SomeOtherObject : public object
{
    public:

    SomeOtherObject(){}
    virtual ~SomeOtherObject(){}

    virtual std::string to_string()
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeOtherObject";
    } 
};

std::map<std::string, std::function<object*()>> types;

template<typename O>
inline
static void register_type(const std::string & name)
{
    types[name] = [](){ return new O; };
}

static object * get_object(const std::string & object_name )
{
    return types[object_name]();
}

int main()
{
    register_type<SomeObject>("SomeObject");
    register_type<SomeOtherObject>("SomeOtherObject");

    object * some = get_object("SomeObject");
    object * some_other = get_object("SomeOtherObject");

    std::cout << "::" << some->to_string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "::" << some_other->to_string() << std::endl;

    delete some;
    delete some_other;

    std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output (-std=c++11 required):**

```
::I am a type of SomeObject
::I am a type of SomeOtherObject 
exit
```

Comment: Suppose you could, what variable type would you use to store the result? And how would you then use that result?

Comment: that helped me find the answer... and it would be void *

Comment: And what do you do with your `void*` after you have it? Do you cast it to a concrete type?

Comment: yep, I know it sounds bad but I would know the base type of the class. And that would be different each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class template that needs one level of indirection but it obviates the need for `SomeObject` and `SomeOtherObject` to derive from `object`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>

class object
{
   public:

      virtual ~object(){}

      virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};

template <typename RealObject>
class TemplateObject : public object
{
   public:

      TemplateObject() : ro_() {}

      virtual std::string to_string()
      {
         return ro_.to_string();
      } 

   private:

      RealObject ro_;
};

std::map<std::string, std::function<object*()>> types;

template<typename O>
inline
static void register_type(const std::string & name)
{
    types[name] = [](){ return new TemplateObject<O>(); };
}

static object * get_object(const std::string & object_name )
{
    return types[object_name]();
}

class SomeObject
{
    public:

    SomeObject(){}
    ~SomeObject(){}

    std::string to_string()
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeObject";
    } 
};

class SomeOtherObject
{
    public:

    SomeOtherObject(){}
    ~SomeOtherObject(){}

    std::string to_string()
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeOtherObject";
    } 
};

int main()
{
    register_type<SomeObject>("SomeObject");
    register_type<SomeOtherObject>("SomeOtherObject");

    object * some = get_object("SomeObject");
    object * some_other = get_object("SomeOtherObject");

    std::cout << "::" << some->to_string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "::" << some_other->to_string() << std::endl;

    delete some;
    delete some_other;

    std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
::I am a type of SomeObject
::I am a type of SomeOtherObject
exit
```

Comment: For more info on this approach, google "Sean Parent concept based polymorphism".

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Amit I came to this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>

class object
{
    public:

    virtual ~object(){}

    virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};

class SomeObject : public object
{
    public:

    SomeObject(){}
    virtual ~SomeObject(){}

    virtual std::string to_string()
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeObject";
    } 
};

class SomeOtherObject : public object
{
    public:

    SomeOtherObject(){}
    virtual ~SomeOtherObject(){}

    virtual std::string to_string()
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeOtherObject";
    } 
};

std::map<std::string, std::function<void*()>> types;

template<typename O>
inline
static void register_type(const std::string & name)
{
    types[name] = [](){ return new O; };
}

static void * get_object(const std::string & object_name )
{
    return types[object_name]();
}

int main()
{
    register_type<SomeObject>("SomeObject");
    register_type<SomeOtherObject>("SomeOtherObject");

    object * some = (object*)get_object("SomeObject");
    object * some_other = (object*)get_object("SomeOtherObject");

    std::cout << "::" << some->to_string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "::" << some_other->to_string() << std::endl;

    delete some;
    delete some_other;

    std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't try to drive you towards this solution. In fact I don't see the point of returning `void*` if you **know** it's really `object*` and immediately cast it.

Comment: I think I can summarize, I have to register 2 kind of objects. 
controller and view. I register everything regardless the inheritance of the class. And in the given time I need to call a controller and It's name is stored in a std::string variable. So I just call (controller*)get_object(variable). Same thing with the view and anything else I need.

Comment: So I'd advise refactoring this code to have a template function `template<typename O> inline static O* get_object (...)` that returns the correct type. Using `void*` has many drawbacks and should be avoided in most cases.

Comment: To make that useful, you'd have to use separate `types ` map for each base type. It's advisable to wrap that in a class to make that organized properly

Comment: Good point, I would have to cast it inside the function anyways but its better to do it myself (inside the library).